# Maximize the sum of second element of tuples based on the sum of the first element in the lists of tuples

Tags: python-3.x

I have several lists of tuples, here I bring two of them as an example:

```
a = [(266.59, 0.0),(269.62, 0.2),(270.91, 0.4),(271.39, 0.6),(271.44, 0.8),(268.94, 1.0)]
b = [(661.47, 0.0),(671.5, 0.2),(678.35, 0.4),(683.31, 0.6),(686.82, 0.8),(689.22, 1.0)]
```

I want to find the pair of tuples in both list when the sum of the first elements is maximized while the sum of the second elements of tuples is equal to 0.8.

Following combinations result in sum of second elements equal to 0.8:

```
[(266.59, 0.0), (686.82, 0.8)] 
[(661.47, 0.0), (271.44, 0.8)]
[(269.62, 0.2), (683.31, 0.6)]
[(671.5, 0.2), (271.39, 0.6)]
[(270.91, 0.4), (678.35, 0.4)]
```

Out of which [(266.59, 0.0), (686.82, 0.8)] gives the maximum sum of 1st elements; 953.41.

In my code, I created the combination of all pairs, filtered them for the sum of second elements to be equal to 0.8, and then found the pair with the maximum sum of the first elements.

Here is the code:

```
In [1] combination = list(itertools.product(a,b))
In [2] _2nd_sum = [list(map(sum, zip(*list(comb))))[1] for  comb  in  combination]
In [3] true_indeces = [i for i,GL in enumerate(_2nd_sum) if GL==0.8]
In [4] selected = [combination[i] for i in true_indeces]
In [5] print(selected)

Out [1] [((266.59, 0.0), (686.82, 0.8)), ((269.62, 0.2), (683.31, 0.6)), ((270.91, 0.4), (678.35, 0.4)), ((271.39, 0.6), (671.5, 0.2)), ((271.44, 0.8), (661.47, 0.0))]

In [6] _1st_sum = [list(map(sum, zip(*list(selected))))[0] for selected  in  selected]
In [7] _1st_Max = max(_1st_sum)
In [8] selected[_1st_sum.index(_1st_Max )]
Out [2] ((266.59, 0.0), (686.82, 0.8))
```

This code works fine when I have few lists of tuples only, but it gives "Memory Error" when the number of lists exceeds 15 due to heavy computation when creating the combination at line 1. Any idea how to solve the problem when dealing with 15 lists or even more?

Comment: Have you tried working with generators?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve when you have more than two lists. Is it still just a pair of tuples? I need to select them from different lists? List A can combine with list B and list C, and so on?

Comment: You generate all combinations first to filter the right ones later. Easy to code, but a waste of computation time. Create candidates with own code/function instead of using `product` skipping from consideration entire branches of combinations. Sort the lists on second tuple item to make it easier to break a loop if the is no chance to get the required sum. The memory issue can be solved by using iterators only, but you will run into a loooong computation time with many lists if you don't skip a huge amount of combinations from being actually evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You generate all combinations first to filter the right ones later. Easy to code, but a waste of computation time. Same thing with looking for the maximum of first sum.

Create candidates with own code/function instead of using product skipping from consideration entire branches of combinations. Sort the lists on second tuple item in reversed order to make it easier to break a loop if the is no chance to get the required sum.

The memory issue can be solved by using iterators only, but you will run into a loooong computation time with many lists if you don't skip a huge amount of combinations from being actually evaluated.

Best you combine the first step with the second going through the combinations checking all conditions at the same time:

- is the second sum already larger than the right one (skips branches of combinations)?
- is the second sum of all tuples lower than the right one (skips branches of combinations)?
- is the second sum the right one?
- is the first sum larger than a maximum from all previous combinations (to remember the tuple combination and the sum  for later checks)?

Below an example how it can be done:

```
a = [(266.59, 0.0),(269.62, 0.2),(270.91, 0.4),(271.39, 0.6),(271.44, 0.8),(268.94, 1.0)]
b = [(661.47, 0.0),(671.5,  0.2),(678.35, 0.4),(683.31, 0.6),(686.82, 0.8),(689.22, 1.0)]

def compare_floats(float_num, prec = 5):
    return int(float_num*10**5)

from operator import itemgetter
LL = [a, b] #, c, d, ...]
tgt_sum_1 = 0.8

lenLL = len(LL)
maxIndx_LL = lenLL-1
maxIndx_l_inLL = []

for l in LL: 
   l.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
   maxIndx_l_inLL.append(len(l)-1)
#print( LL )

indx_tpl_of_l_inLL = [0]*lenLL
#print(indx_tpl_of_l_inLL, maxIndx_l_inLL)
max_sum_0 = 0.0
indx_tpl_of_l_inLL_for_max_sum = None
import time

indx_to_increase = lenLL-1
while indx_tpl_of_l_inLL[0] <= maxIndx_l_inLL[0]:
    print(indx_tpl_of_l_inLL, end=' # ')
    sum_1 = 0.0
    increase_indx_only = False
    time.sleep(0.25)
    for i in range(lenLL):
        sum_1 += LL[i][indx_tpl_of_l_inLL[i]][1]
        if compare_floats(sum_1) > compare_floats(tgt_sum_1):
            indx_to_increase = i
            increase_indx_only = True
            break

    print(sum_1, tgt_sum_1, end=' ## ')
    if increase_indx_only:
        print(f'{indx_to_increase=}')

    if not increase_indx_only and compare_floats(sum_1) < compare_floats(tgt_sum_1):
        indx_tpl_of_l_inLL[indx_to_increase] = maxIndx_l_inLL[indx_to_increase]
        print('sum_1 < tgt_sum_1 ', indx_tpl_of_l_inLL)
        increase_indx_only = True 

    if not increase_indx_only:
        print('sum_1 == tgt_sum_1', indx_tpl_of_l_inLL)
        assert compare_floats(sum_1) == compare_floats(tgt_sum_1)
        if indx_tpl_of_l_inLL_for_max_sum is None: 
            indx_tpl_of_l_inLL_for_max_sum = [indx_tpl_of_l_inLL]
            max_sum = sum(LL[i][indx_tpl_of_l_inLL[i]][0] for i in range(lenLL))
            print(f'max_sum={max_sum} at {indx_tpl_of_l_inLL}')
        else:
            cur_sum = sum(LL[i][indx_tpl_of_l_inLL[i]][0] for i in range(lenLL))
            if compare_floats(cur_sum) == compare_floats(max_sum): 
                indx_tpl_of_l_inLL_for_max_sum += [indx_tpl_of_l_inLL[:]] # [:] make a copy
            elif compare_floats(cur_sum) > compare_floats(max_sum):
                indx_tpl_of_l_inLL_for_max_sum = [indx_tpl_of_l_inLL[:]]
                max_sum = cur_sum
                print(f'new max_sum={max_sum} at {indx_tpl_of_l_inLL}')

    while indx_tpl_of_l_inLL[indx_to_increase] == maxIndx_l_inLL[indx_to_increase]:
        indx_tpl_of_l_inLL[indx_to_increase] = 0
        indx_to_increase -= 1

    if indx_to_increase < 0: 
        break

    indx_tpl_of_l_inLL[indx_to_increase] += 1
    indx_to_increase = lenLL-1

print('---------------------------')
print([ LL[i][j] for i, j in enumerate(indx_tpl_of_l_inLL_for_max_sum[0])], max_sum, indx_tpl_of_l_inLL_for_max_sum)
```

which outputs:

```
[0, 0] # 1.0 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=0
[1, 0] # 1.8 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[1, 1] # 1.6 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[1, 2] # 1.4 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[1, 3] # 1.2000000000000002 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[1, 4] # 1.0 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[1, 5] # 0.8 0.8 ## sum_1 == tgt_sum_1 [1, 5]
max_sum=932.9100000000001 at [1, 5]
[2, 0] # 1.6 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[2, 1] # 1.4 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[2, 2] # 1.2 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[2, 3] # 1.0 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[2, 4] # 0.8 0.8 ## sum_1 == tgt_sum_1 [2, 4]
new max_sum=942.89 at [2, 4]
[2, 5] # 0.6 0.8 ## sum_1 < tgt_sum_1  [2, 5]
[3, 0] # 1.4 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[3, 1] # 1.2000000000000002 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[3, 2] # 1.0 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[3, 3] # 0.8 0.8 ## sum_1 == tgt_sum_1 [3, 3]
new max_sum=949.26 at [3, 3]
[3, 4] # 0.6000000000000001 0.8 ## sum_1 < tgt_sum_1  [3, 5]
[4, 0] # 1.2 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[4, 1] # 1.0 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[4, 2] # 0.8 0.8 ## sum_1 == tgt_sum_1 [4, 2]
new max_sum=952.93 at [4, 2]
[4, 3] # 0.6000000000000001 0.8 ## sum_1 < tgt_sum_1  [4, 5]
[5, 0] # 1.0 0.8 ## indx_to_increase=1
[5, 1] # 0.8 0.8 ## sum_1 == tgt_sum_1 [5, 1]
new max_sum=953.4100000000001 at [5, 1]
[5, 2] # 0.6 0.8 ## sum_1 < tgt_sum_1  [5, 5]
---------------------------
[(266.59, 0.0), (686.82, 0.8)] 953.4100000000001 [[5, 1]]
```

From the output you can see that large branches of combinations are skipped. Notice that the floats of sums are not always as expected making it necessary to limit float precision and use integer equivalents for comparison purposes.

The code above handles the case of multiple combinations with the same `max_sum` storing them as indices lists in a `indx_tpl_of_l_inLL_for_max_sum` list.

Comment: Thank you Claudio. I tried this out and the processing speed when number of lists is big, is still extremely low. As a matter of fact, if you plot first element versus the second element of each list, you will likely see an upward trend toward a maximum followed by a decreasing trend. To optimize the sum of the first elements while keep the sum of second element equal or below a specific number (here 0.8), we can discard those tuples on the decline trend plus those with the second item greater than 0.8, off the lists. This will help the code to be faster but still not efficient enough.

Comment: Please don't be greedy and change the requirement after having got a solution to the issue which was the reason for your question (Memory Error). The proposed solution solves not only the memory overflow problem, but provides a speed advantage. I suggest you accept the answer and ask another question if there is a way to increase the speed of the computation given additional information about the specifics of the data distribution in the lists and specifics of the lists (are all equal length? etc.).

Comment: In other words: I am done here with my answer. There will be no updates to it.